Book about girl with violet eyes
I read a series many many years ago and I cannot remember the name. From what I can remember, the main character is a girl with violet eyes who has telekinetic powers I believe. She dates a boy with golden eyes who can shapeshift I believe. But another lover interest comes in. I believe they go to some type of school or camp where they all have powers, but she is really important for some reason. Eventually throughout the series there is a rebellion and they end up travelling underground.

A girl, with violet eyes, in YA fiction? That should be easy to find.

"a fantasy book a read more than 5 years ago. About a girl who starts going to a specialized school for powers. There are a few details I remember, like her violet eyes with golden streaks when her power activates, a guy with the power of fire who's hands are all black because they're burnt up. There was a scene in the forest where she almost created some sort of electric storm. It's weird how hard it is to find, almost as if it disappeared or never existed (how dramatic, I know)" - https://live-legacy-admin.nypl.org/blog/2017/11/22/finding-book-forgotten-title?page=21 - Same book, maybe

It's a long shot, but how about the Violet eyes series by Nicole Luiken.
It matches a lot of your description. The girl is Angel Eastland and the boy is Michael Vallant. They are part of a secret experiment and have been modified to give them the Renaissance gene that confers advanced mental powers. The bad guy running the experiment is Dr. Frankenstein (no, really!).
However the powers aren't supernatural and Mike has violet eyes like Angel. There is a book in the series called Golden Eyes - possibly that's what you are remembering.
